# html5 required is not allowing button click action to fireup

Tags: asp.net, html, input, attributes, required

I have an input page where i want to create some required fields and some aren't.
That means that at the first part of the form, you can select the date by pressing a button to show a calender to select the desired date, adding users (by pressing a button) and then you add the required text and finally a submit button.

Right now, when I put the required attribute to the input tag, the first two buttons don't work. They don't fire up and it writes that first I need to insert the required items.
How can I remove the connection between those specific buttons and the required inputs?

Thanks, Arkadi.

Code:

```
<h3> Create New Project</h3>
Users Added: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
    ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblAdded" runat="server" Text="Label" >User Was Already Added</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblNotFound" runat="server" Text="Label" >User Was Not Found</asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>

Add User<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br /><br />

Project Name: <input ID="txtName" runat="server" required="required" />

Hand Over Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHandOverDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" Text="SelectDate" 
             OnClick="btnSelectDate_Click" />
         <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="False" 
             OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>

Hand Over Form: <input ID="txtHandOverForm" runat="server" required="required"/>
Subject: <input ID="txtSubjectField" runat="server" required="required" />
Project Porpuse <input ID="txtPorpuse" runat="server" required="required" />
Perimiters<input ID="txtPerimiters" runat="server" required="required" />
Comments <textarea id="txtComments" runat="server"></textarea>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: the fact that your buttons aren't working is probably nothing to do with the required attribute. please post sample code so we can help identify the problem

Comment: Thanks for the replays, Code has been added

Comment: this is asp.net code. an asp.net tag would be nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I wanted, so to all those who will see this:
I just needed to change the type of the button from submit to command, that means adding the attribute `UseSubmitBehavior` to false.

Thanks for the Answers, this site is great!

Answer (score 0):

The OnClick events run at the server, but the required attrib is preventing the code from being submitted. If you want to run client side (ie javascript) code, then you will need to use the OnClientClick event instead.

Comment: what is your OnClickClick trying to run? You will need a javascript function for it to run, which then updates the required field. The method should return true to submit the form to the server and run the OnClick method at the server. It seems you should do some reading to gain a better understanding of how asp.net apps work. See this http://forums.asp.net/t/1249580.aspx/1

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know javascript.
I understood the info from the link but i didn't understand what do you mean by "which then updates the required field".
I want to be able to press the button without the form being submitted, and to be able to do that before completing all the required values.